# "put -r" in sftp fails with "Invalid flag"

Tags: linux, sftp, solaris

I'm using Linux server and want to transfer some directories into another server which has Solaris as OS. when I'm connection to server using `sftp` and transferring it is showing error:

```
sftp> lpwd
Local working directory: /home/test
sftp> ls
test
sftp> put -r test/
Invalid flag -r
```

I want to transfer directory and sub-directories all using `sftp`. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There's no `-r` flag in OpenSSH `sftp` `put` command.

An upload in this client is always recursive.

So use just:

```
put test/
```

Or

```
put test/ /target/directory/
```

Answer (score 0):

To put the files recursively you need to have the directory `test` created. So use

```
mkdir test
```

and then

```
put test/
```

of you can use `scp` which have such flag

Comment: yes created folder test and then given put test/  : it is showing again error Couldn't read from "/home/test/temp1": Is a directory

Comment: @vijayDaggumati, you should have entire directory tree created on the target.